Managed code cannot be debugged in VS2022 without Enable Native code debugging
on two out of three development PC's I have the following issue.
VB.net app, all managed code.
Debug only works if "Enable native code debugging" is enabled
The issue started after VS2022 preview Update 4 was installed. But once that had been done even un-installing and running InstallCleanup.exe have not resolved the issue. This makes me suspect a setting within the app rather than VS
Click start, build runs and completes and then nothing happens, ie no debug. The built app in the debug folder runs fine.
Change settings Debug-> Enable native code debugging and then debug runs, but HotReload is disabled
There are no error messages other than the program existed, 0x0 which is normal.
Any steps to locate the source of the issue, logs etc?

Temporarily disable the installed security software and try again.

Will it affect your newly created projects?
Check the Debug>Option to see if there are differences between your PCs' Visual Studio.
